# How do I disable my laptop battery?

Tags: power-management, battery

I got a look at my laptop battery when it was opened for service and it was dangerously swollen. I didn't know the reason for the crack near my touch pad until I saw the battery. I don't want to disconnect the battery; I just want to disable it so I can re-enable it without having to screw open my laptop when I am doing something that doesn't have auto-save.

I know I should get the battery replaced but I don't want to spend on the battery because I am intending to get a new laptop in less than an year.

I am using Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS.

Comment: "Swollen Batteries" can be dangerous. In worst case they will burn down your house.

Comment: Check your details, and if you're still using 20.04.5 then please apply security fixes to your system asap. You can read https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2023/03/23/ubuntu-20-04-6-lts-released/ which shows the ISO release date for 20.04.6, but installed systems upgraded to it before that date (*the notifications being the ISO release date only*)

Comment: realize that even if you disable the battery, just being connected might be enough to set it off. Remove that battery ASAP!

Comment: I agree: remove it or have it removed by someone that repairs notebooks. Leaving it in if it is swollen is hazardous. There is also a liability problem: your insurance company might take issue if they ever found out your notebook caught fire and you knew it could happen.

Answer (score 4):

If your battery is swollen, it should be removed and properly discarded *immediately*. It is a **SAFETY HAZARD**. You should still be able to run the machine plugged in.

Don't screw around with a house fire waiting to happen.